# Is there any possible way to add a sidebar while inserting new spreadsheet to drive programmatically?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I want to add sidebar when I am generating a new spreadsheet to my drive.

```
var file = Drive.Files.insert({
    "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
    "parents": [{
      id: folderId
    }],
    "title": 'Linked spreadsheets'
  });
```

Comment: In order to do that, you would need to either bind an apps script file to the new spreadsheet file, or install an add-on to the new spreadsheet.  With the new Apps Script API, you can manage projects.  I have not done it, but it looks like you might be able to attach a script to an existing Sheet.  See the documentation at the following link: [REST Resource: projects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects)  You will need to use OAuth2 and use a particular scope.  I don't have the code or know the details for how to do that.

Comment: What do you mean by "add a sidebar"?

Comment: You would need to create a new script file and then attach it to the Sheet.  As an alternative, you could have a spreadsheet template with a script already bound to it, and copy the file instead of creating a new file and trying to create a new script file and attach it to the Sheet.  If you do want to attach a script to the Sheet, you'll need to use the `parentId` parameter, which will be the file ID of the Sheet.